# How to Create See More Toggle for Each Item in View Accessed by Ng Repeat Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a basic search feature where a user searches for a course and returns the course number and title.  I would like the option to toggle additional information by hitting a drop down arrow next to each course, but in my current implementation the toggling only applies to the first course in the collection of courses accessed in the ng-repeat directive, but would like to be able to "see more" unique information of each individual course. (Trying to model it after this tutorial: https://www.silvabokis.com/squarespace-tips/how-to-create-hideshow-faqs-in-squarespace)

Here is my code: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/qpyvZuvI8vw8q6on?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Any additional fixes towards proper code structure, usability, and/or readability are also appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a plain JS function, you can just use Angulars `ng-click` and `ng-if`, like this to toggle the description:

```
<ul>
  <li class="angular-with-newlines" ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:searchText"> 
    {{course.course_number}}: {{course.title}}
    <button ng-click="course.showDesc=!course.showDesc">See More</button> 
    <div ng-if="course.showDesc"> Description: {{course.description}} </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will set the attribute `showDesc` to true on each course when you click the course's button. If it is set to true, the Description will show up because of the `ng-if`. If you click again, `showDesc` is set to false **=> toggle!**

You can remove the `toggle_visibility` function!

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I was missing out on angular functionality!